# Error while installing oracledb npm

Tags: node.js, oracle

I tried to install oracledb npm but i am getting below error.

[image]

**Already installed :**

- nodejs v6.11.0
- npm 3.10.10
- python 2.7
- visual studio 14
- instant client for oracle 64bit
- windows 10 64bit

**Environment variable in system**

- Path = C:\Oracle\instantclient
- Path = C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\
- Path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_11\bin
- Path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin
- OCI_INC_DIR = C:\Oracle\instantclient\sdk\include
- OCI_LIB_DIR = C:\Oracle\instantclient\sdk\lib\msvc
- Path = C:\Python27\

**ERROR :**

```
C:\>npm install oracledb

> oracledb@1.13.1 install C:\node_modules\oracledb
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\node_modules\oracledb>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 538, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 514, in gyp_main
    options.duplicate_basename_check)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 98, in Load
    generator.CalculateVariables(default_variables, params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1900, in CalculateVariables
    generator_flags.get('msvs_version', 'auto'))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSVersion.py", line 434, in SelectVisualStudioVersion
    versions = _DetectVisualStudioVersions(version_map[version], 'e' in version)
KeyError: '2014'
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:305:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\node_modules\oracledb
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "oracledb"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! oracledb@1.13.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the oracledb@1.13.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the oracledb package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs oracledb
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls oracledb
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: The output says make sure you have the latest versions of Node and NPM, but you appear to be using Node 5.4.11. Also make sure your version of Node is 64 bit to match the Oracle client you have installed.

Comment: @jpmc26 Upgrade the npm and node.js to latest version but still it gives the same error.

Comment: @jpmc26 node.js and oracle client both are 64 bit.

Comment: Oh, Oracle. Why does your *Node* client require **Python**? Python 3 is not compatible with Python 2.7. I've generally had a hard time making sure that package managers can find Visual Studio, too. You might need to launch one of the special VS command prompts. You should also edit those details into the question, not just mention them in the comments.

Comment: There are 3 python installed into system. - python 2.7.11(64 bit), python 2.7.13(32 bit), python 3.6.0(64 bit) so shall i remove all the version?

Comment: I think you should read the [INSTALL doc](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md) since it explains what to do about multiple Python versions.

Comment: @jpmc26 its not so much the Oracle driver that requires it, but rather node-gyp that is used to build the native binaries on install. node-gyp is commonly used to build natives, you can't really blame the authors of the driver for using something that already exists in the wild. Unfortunately, building natives in a Windows environment is not exactly hassle free. This github page pretty much sums up the pain experienced here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629

Comment: @Gimby Even Python decided that trying to build binaries on the fly at install time is a bad way to go. That's why it has wheels. (Wheels for Linux are rare, but having an install in the distro's package repository is common.) Why is there a node library to call out to Python's build system in a way that isn't even recommended by the Python community? And given that we're talking about *Oracle* here (a company not exactly wanting for resources), why is there not just a prebuilt installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the msvs-version :

> npm config set msvs_version 2015

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is you are using **unsupported Node version**.

Version of node you are using is 5.**, and oracle db module supports node 4, 6 and 7.

Source is [git](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb) of the module.

Please upgrade node version to 6 or 7.

Power shell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

or use nvm:

```
nvm install 6
nvm use 6
```

In environmental variables make sure that **Python 2.7** is being pointed at and only 2.7.* .

No need to uninstall all other pythones versions.

Update me on how it goes;

Good luck,

Comment: `-Scope Process` would change the execution policy without leaving any side effects on the system.

Comment: Same as running:
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass, this is done when executing unsigned scripts

Comment: No unwanted side effects, after closing the PS session it will be default behavior.

Comment: I set the python path into system. still it gives me same error.

Comment: @sBanda You don't know whether the OP *wants* to set the default execution policy to `Unrestricted`. That's the point.